# Query optimization in EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

While profiling my application (and DB), I found a huge query (of about 200 lines) in the profiler that looks like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project2].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    ---
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
         --- 
       CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[MemberID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
            ---
            FROM   [MST].[User] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [FW].[Role] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RoleID] = [Extent2].[RoleID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [MST].[Society] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[SocietyID] = [Extent3].[SocietyID]
            WHERE [Extent1].[UserName] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [MST].[Member] AS [Extent4] ON [Limit1].[UserID] = [Extent4].[UserID]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[UserID] ASC, [Project2].[RoleID1] ASC, [Project2].[SocietyID2] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='xxx'
```

The source of the query is -

```
var d1=db.Users.Include("Role").Include("Society").Include("Members").First(m => m.UserName == username);
```

The same I could achieve by splitting the code into four different statements (not sure about the right way to do with EF)

```
var data = db.Users.First(m => m.UserName == username);
var x = data.Role;
var y = data.Society;
var z = data.Members;
```

which generates four lean queries as:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    ---
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserName] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='xxx'
go

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[RoleID] AS [RoleID], 
    ---
    FROM [FW].[Role] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[RoleID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=16
go

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[SocietyID] AS [SocietyID], 
    ---
    WHERE [Extent1].[SocietyID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=6
go

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[MemberID] AS [MemberID], 
    ---
    FROM [MST].[Member] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=19
go
```

So, in order to boost the performance (and with less maintenance overhead) what is the better way of building the EF queries?

Comment: How complex a query looks is not directly related to how efficient it is, your 4 "lean" queries look like they would probably be slower than the "complex" query. Have you identified that the complex query is actually slow. If so I would look at adding appropriate indexes rather than getting EF to generate prettier SQL.

Comment: Entity Framework is notorious in its overly-complex generated SQL queries. We expect version 7 to introduce some improvements though.

Comment: Though I haven't measured the performance of those queries, I  believe there would be. The first query has inner joins, left outer joins and sort, which is straightly dependent on no. of child records, while the the other queries are pretty straight forward. Also I need to see what if I include few more tables, and query length is beyond 8000 chars.